# python broadcasting message via server

Tags: python, server, broadcast

I am trying to broadcast a message to the subnet and i am giving the subnet address to the server to connect and the client throws error saying name or service unknown and not receiving the packet. Could anyone please tell me how do i broadcast message to my subnet such that client can also get that message or packet. exactly in the address area. My main doubts are about. which address is given at the client side and server side.

Error i get at client side is :

```
sending
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Threaded-server.py", line 11, in <module>
    sent=s.sendto(msg.encode(),address)
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
closing socket

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Thanks

## client

```
import socket
import sys
import json


connected = False

#connect to server
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect((' ',10000))
connected = True

while connected == True:
    #wait for server commands to do things, now we will just display things
    data = client_socket.recv(1024)     
    cmd = json.loads(data) #we now only expect json    
    if(cmd['type'] == 'bet'):
        bet = cmd['value']
        print('betting is: '+bet)
    elif (cmd['type'] == 'result'):        
        print('winner is: '+str(cmd['winner']))
        print('payout is: '+str(cmd['payout']))


##Server

import socket, time, sys
import threading
import pprint

TCP_IP = '192.168.1.255'
TCP_PORT = 10000
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

clientCount = 0

class server():

    def __init__(self):
        self.CLIENTS = []        


    def startServer(self):
        try:
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            s.bind((TCP_IP,TCP_PORT))
            s.listen(10)
            while 1:
                client_socket, addr = s.accept()
                print ('Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))
                global clientCount
                clientCount = clientCount+1
                print (clientCount)
                # register client
                self.CLIENTS.append(client_socket)
                threading.Thread(target=self.playerHandler, args=(client_socket,)).start()
            s.close()
        except socket.error as msg:
            print ('Could Not Start Server Thread. Error Code : ') #+ str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
            sys.exit()


   #client handler :one of these loops is running for each thread/player   
    def playerHandler(self, client_socket):
        #send welcome msg to new client
        client_socket.send(bytes('{"type": "bet","value": "1"}', 'UTF-8'))
        while 1:
            data = client_socket.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
            if not data: 
                break
            #print ('Data : ' + repr(data) + "\n")
            #data = data.decode("UTF-8")
            # broadcast
            for client in self.CLIENTS.values():
                client.send(data)

         # the connection is closed: unregister
        self.CLIENTS.remove(client_socket)
        #client_socket.close() #do we close the socket when the program ends? or for ea client thead?

    def broadcast(self, message):

        for c in self.CLIENTS:
            c.send(message.encode("utf-8"))

    def _broadcast(self):        
        for sock in self.CLIENTS:           
            try :
                self._send(sock)
            except socket.error:                
                sock.close()  # closing the socket connection
                self.CLIENTS.remove(sock)  # removing the socket from the active connections list

    def _send(self, sock):        
        # Packs the message with 4 leading bytes representing the message length
        #msg = struct.pack('>I', len(msg)) + msg
        # Sends the packed message
        sock.send(bytes('{"type": "bet","value": "1"}', 'UTF-8'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = server() #create new server listening for connections
    threading.Thread(target=s.startServer).start()

    while 1:       
        s._broadcast()
        pprint.pprint(s.CLIENTS)
        print(len(s.CLIENTS)) #print out the number of connected clients every 5s
        time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Can you please copy/paste the exact error message and mark the line at which the error happens?